# meaning and relevant values for azure functions resource manager template parameters.json

Tags: azure, powershell, templates, parameters, azure-resource-manager

**status update:**  It appears the example values I was looking for were right there in front of me in the <resource group name> | automation script | template | parameters view and also if I click "Deploy" it produces a pretty UI with examples for all the parameters.json file entries defined based on the resource group settings that the script is derived from.

I created with azure portal wizard a resource group and within it a function app where the wizard created an associated consumption based app service plan, storage account and application insights resources to support it.

I then used the resource group's | settings | automation script | deployment option to get the template.json, parameters.json and bash deploy.sh / powershell deploy.ps1 scripts to automate recreating this configuration in another azure subscription, or same subscription but different resource group.

The issue i'm running into is what the meaning is and relevant values are for a few of the parameters i'm finding in the parameters.json shown below.  When I run bash deploy.sh / powershell deploy.ps1 scripts I make it to the point of it processing the last parameter where it appears to fail.  I've placed ??? marks beside entries below where it isn't clear what the value should look like and applies to.  I haven't been able to find any insights in search hits or script error output suggested https://aka.ms/arm-deploy and https://aka.ms/arm-template/#resources references.

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "sites_myfuncapp_name": {
        "value": "myfuncapp1"
    },
    "components_myfuncapp_name": {
        "value": "myfuncapp1" ???
    },
    "storageAccounts_mystoracct_name": {
        "value": "mystoracct1"
    },
    "config_web_name": {
        "value": "myfuncapp1" ???
    },
    "serverfarms_myappsvcplan_name": {
        "value": "myappsvcplan1"
    },
    "alertrules_Failure_Anomalies___myfuncapp_name": {
        "value": "myfuncapp1" ???
    },
    "hostNameBindings_myfuncapp.azurewebsites.net_name": {
        "value": "myfuncapp1"  ???
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I believe what you need is something like.... ```"alertrules_Failure_Anomalies___myfuncapp_name": {
            "defaultValue": "myfuncapp1",
            "type": "String"
        }```

Comment: thanks for reply see status update section of original question where it seems example values were staring me right in the face.